# Separating data and time column in gridview

Tags: date, gridview, time, bind

I am new to ASP.net and C#.

I have a `datetime` column in SQL Server. I want to bind the date part in date column of gridview and time part of datetime column of SQL Server in time column of the gridview. Also I would like to know how can I make columns of my own in gridview.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us your attempts at writing the code or queries

Comment: It's best to do that on the sql side.  either split the datetime field to date and time fields (modern versions of sqlserver support this, IIRC).  or have the select statement break the datetime field it apart via cast()/convert() function calls.  In either case then you won't have to do anything special on the ASP side of things

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will try this.